# What does this regular expression do exactly?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

The PHP code is:

```
$cleanedVer = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.,a-z,A-Z-]/','',$someVer);
```

It cleans the version sting but sometimes cleans too much info.

I'm not sure what this [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) regular expression do to the the string in the above snippet. Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It removes any character which is **not** an alphanumeric, dot (.), commas (,) or hyphen (-).

Comment: It also does not remove commas!

Comment: @Mathletics Inside the brackets you have an enumeration (list separator is ,). What does ^ means in the first list element?

Comment: @AlexV inside `[]` the `^` character means 'not', so the regex will match any character not specified in the set.

Comment: @Mathletics Ahh I see, and if I want to keep spaces too do I just add ", " to the list (without quotes of course)?

Comment: @AlexV no, just ` ` with no comma. The comma is not a special character and shouldn't be used as a list separator. [at least not in this context] The original regex should be reduced to `/[^0-9,.a-zA-Z-]/` and including spaces would be `/[^0-9,.a-zA-Z- ]/`.

Comment: @Sammitch Great, I understand now. I saw the comma as a list separator but I understand it is not now. Thanks!

Comment: @Sammitch And if I which to srip commas too this would be valid?: `/[^0-9.a-zA-Z- ]/`

Comment: @AlexV yes it would. Although, place the `-` at the end of the character class to be sure not to mess things up as it has a special meaning. So `/[^0-9.a-zA-Z -]/` (not saying it was wrong).